# Typescript function extended interface type

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I have a function which takes an array of objects which do not have an id property and return all those objects with an id property added to them.

```
const pickIdAndDocs = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(doc => ({
    id: 1,
    ...doc
  }))
}
```

Now, for example if i have this interface

```
interface iUser {
  name: string;
}
```

and an array containing values of type **iUser**

```
let users: iUser[] = [ {name: "John"}, {name: "Joe"} ];
```

How do i specify the return type of the function **pickIdAndDocs**, such that it returns an array where each item is an extended type of the input type it takes with an added id property

```
function pickIdAndDocs<T>(items : T[] ) : extendedT[];
```

This function can take an array of any type (will always be objects/key-value pairs), an return all items with an appended id property.

Or am i approaching this the wrong way? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially we want to build up new type by combining two types. One with `{id: number}` and another is whatever passed to the function. This exactly what [`intersection type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) does. Assuming my interpretation of your problem is correct, I think this is what you want:

```ts
interface User {
  name: string;
}

type WithId<T> = T & { id: number };

const pickIdAndDocs = <T,>(arr: T[]): WithId<T>[] => {
  return arr.map((doc) => ({
    id: 1,
    ...doc,
  }));
};

let users: User[] = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Joe" }];

const usersWithId = pickIdAndDocs(users);

// No warning!
usersWithId[0].id;
usersWithId[0].name;

// Warning: Property 'age' does not exist on type 'WithId<User>'.
usersWithId[0].age;
```

Here is the TS Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/ND5B4m

Comment: Which service do you use for short url?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I use a third party plugin as described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-playground-link-shortener

Comment: This looks great. I will try it out. Thanks